# Special education AI assistant

Tags: speech-recognition, artificial-intelligence

I saw a video of a robot used in special education with children on the autism spectrum (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQcjfebQXgQ). My son isn't autistic, he has Tourette Syndrome, ADHD, executive function problems, and OCD. A digital assistant could be quite helpful for him. All I need it to do is have an interactive conversation with him.

Here's an example. As my son is getting ready for bed, he needs someone to talk him through his steps, give him positive feedback, and ask questions like "Okay, you're in your pajamas. Great! What else do you need to do to get ready for bed?" And the assistant would have a mental list (preprogrammed) of everything that's needed (brush teeth, wash face, put on eczema ointment, put dirty clothes in hamper). My son is 12 and would like to get ready by himself -- without Mama or Papa -- but he gets sidetracked when he's in his room on his own. The robot doesn't need to be able to "see" him brushing his teeth. He just needs to be able to hear my son saying, "I brushed my teeth." When the two of them together decide he has made it through his routine, then they can call me in, and I'll check, and then we'll do our bedtime reading.

That's an example of what I have in mind. There are other situations where I could imagine an assistant being helpful for him.

I'd like a system where I can provide some custom instructions.

Comment: Does it really have to be a Web app? If not, for which operating system? Does the assistant need to have a graphical representation (e.g., a face), or is voice-only okay?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  That was probably the wrong tag to choose.  I will try to remove it.  Actually, I was hoping for a stand-alone gadget or robot.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then this would be off-topic here, as we only recommend software, not hardware (btw, there is a [proposal for a Hardware Recommendation site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations?referrer=E9UyPC567ihg1JcHSmnJDQ2)). So would a solution for a smartphone/computer work? If yes, you should state for which system(s) you’d need this. If not, then we should close this question here.

Comment: I don't know what system I would want to use for this.  Look, this is the third forum I've tried.  Somehow every forum I try is the "wrong" one.